# Can I use 1 pass with same serial and same passTypeID to many users?

Tags: ios6, passbook

I create a pass dynamically. Each pass has some different contents such as primary field, secondary field, but all pass has same serial and passTypeID, so is it right to do like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `serialNumber` and `PassTypeIdentifier` can be the same, even if each pass has different contents.  However, there are a couple of things to consider.

Passbook will only allow one Pass of with the same `serialNumber` and `passTypeIdentifier` combination at any one time.  This means that if user A has a pass installed with a `primaryField` key of `name` containing a value of `Malin`, then user A trys to install a second pass that contains a `primaryField` key of `name` containing a value of `Nick`, then Passbook will treat this as an update of the orignal pass and will replace `Marlin's` pass with `Nick's` pass.

Using the same `serialNumber` and `PassTypeIdentifier` can have advantages in that it prevents users loading multiple copies of the same pass on a single device. But sometimes it may not be what you need (E.g. a parent wanting to hold both their own and their child's boarding passes).

If you use the same serialNumber, then you need to consider how you uniquely identify pass records in your database.  You don't want a situation where crediting `Malin's` pass with 1,000 points, also credit's everyone else's pass.

We use the `authenticationToken` as a unique key because it is supplied in the 3 of the 4 pass related methods of the [Passbook Web Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988) (Register, Unregister and Refresh).  Unfortunately, it isn't provided in the `Getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device` method, so we add the authenticationToken to the devices table to provide a common key so we can check the pass record to see if it has been updated.

Comment: Thank you! I will think about it whether to change or not !

Comment: if a user shares a pass they have to one of their friends, does their friend's device have the same authentication token and serial number?

Comment: Yes it does - the pass is an identical clone. Same applies if a pass syncs with another device over iCloud.